# CSS Hyperlink Colors Not Consistent for Link, Visited, Hover, Active

Tags: css, hyperlink, hover

I'm currently using CSS to change the hyperlink colors in my left navigation but there seems to be some inconsistency. Some links will take the correct properties I have declared, whereas, other links won't accept them. I have declared the same `class nav` to all the links. There isn't any overwriting that I know of for these links since it's isolated.

Below is the left navigation code snippet

This works:

```
var context='<%=request.getContextPath()%>';
<%--    var sOrg = '<%=sOrg%>'; --%>
document.write("<div id=\"leftNav\">");
document.write("<div id=\"leftNavtext\"><a href=\"home.htm?sOrg="+'<%=sOrg%>'+"\" class=\"nav\" id=\"phome\" style=\"text-decoration:none\" >Home</a></div>");
```

Then this doesn't work:

```
  <% if(roles.contains("PEIMSDataCompleter")) {  %>
document.write("<div id=\"leftNavtext\" ><a href=\"dataSubmissions.jsp\" class=\"nav\" id=\"dataSubmissions\" style=\"text-decoration:none\">Data Submissions</a></div>");
```

Then this works:

```
document.write("<div  style=\" padding-left: 20px;padding-top:5px;\"><a href=\"scheduleMonitor.htm\" class=\"nav\" id=\"scheduleMonitor\" style=\"text-decoration:none\">Monitor Data Loads</a></div>");
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#leftNav {
width:180px;
height:687px;
background-color:#E0F0F2;
margin-bottom:15px;
padding-left:10px;
text-decoration:none;
text-color: #0083cc;
}

#leftNavtext {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:800;
font-size:95%;
color:#0083cc;
width:auto;
padding: 20px 10px 3px 0px;



}

#noteBody{
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:800;
font-size:95%;
width:960px;
margin:auto;

}

// Below is the code for getting the hyperlink text to be formatted correctly (ie link colors)
a.nav:link {color: #0083cc; text-decoration: none; }
a.nav:visited {color: #0083cc; text-decoration: none; }
a.nav:hover {color: orange; text-decoration: underline; }
a.nav:active {color: #0083cc; }
```

As far as I can see, there are no differences between these two links. These are just a few of the many links I have in the left navigation and this happens randomly. I'm currently using IE 9 and this browser is my requirement.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: just as a note for your document.write's, you won't have to escape every double quote if you use surround the string with single quotes, such as document.write('<div id="leftNavtext">'). I find this helps avoid hard to spot issues.

Comment: Have you checked for any conflicting rules for the dataSubmissions id?

Comment: Have you used your Browser Tool's DOM inspector to see what's over-riding?

Comment: I've looked at the Browser DOM inspector and it shows that the style is applied. The odd thing is that hover works..just `link` doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Did you formated all :pseudo stated of your anchors ?

```
a, a:link, a:visited {some.css}
a:hover, a:visited:hover, a:active, a:focus {some-other.css}
```

Perhaps you are looking at a browser specific styling.

Comment: I added your suggestion but it didn't fix the problem. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

First of all,

- `text-color` property doesn't exists ; use `color` instead.
- If you're using ASP (it seems to), please add the appropriate tag to your question

Next, the problem isn't due to your CSS ; see this tiny JSFiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/j8ruV/2/

The fact is you're dynamically adding objects to your page with the document.write() method, but this method adds your `divs` weirdly to the DOM, and so they're not considered by the CSS (except for the inline one). By simply testing with the `.innerHTML` property, this seems to work (see the fiddle).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've changed `text-color` to `color`. I'm not using ASP. I used `document.innerHTML` and it works for one of the links. For the other ones, it disappears and messed up the entire left nav menu.

Comment: @Richard You're welcome! Could you fork the fiddle and implement your bug, and share it for us to help?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to place inline code for the links:

`document.write("<div id=\"leftNavtext\" ><a href=\"dataSubmissions.jsp\" class=\"nav\" id=\"dataSubmissions\" style=\"text-decoration:none; color:#0083cc;\">Data Submissions</a></div>");`

Comment: That not might be the most maintenable code, but glad you've find a workaround! Don't forget to mark an answer as "Accepted"